# Extract string from file based on multiple patterns in a file

Tags: java, regex, thymeleaf, talend

I have multiple formats in which the required string can come in a column of csv file . Formats are like :

```
 NOTPROVIDED 3392076122/RFB/2006270519020060 
 

 3392076122 4031253506 RAMIN ABD ULJABAR AF/RFB/202006

 
 NOTPROVIDED 3392076122 EASTERN U/RFB/200627
```

Any of the above formats can appear in the file and I need to extract "3392076122" from all above patterns and the formats are dynamic and will keep on changing. Instead of using modifying java code each time and using substring etc i am looking for a solution which can be updated dynamically on the fly using some template engine like FTL,Thymeleaf . How can this be achieved ?

If not with template engine kindly suggest the regex for extracting from above formats.

Edit : Does ETL tool like Talend have any better solution for handling this

Comment: Doesn't look like a fitting task for a template engine, as those operate in the opposite direction. Probably you should use a regular expression with a capturing group instead. Then store the regular expression in some configuration file or database that you re-read sometimes.

Comment: When parsing `3392076122 4031253506`, how would you know that the first number is the correct one?

Comment: That's the format I will need to predefine .in the second case it will be (number) (number) (string) etc. In this case pick up the first number....similarly for rest of the other formats I will predefine .but how to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

**Maybe this will give you some hints on how to extract with regex considering your input string:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // We assume that the rows from the file has
    // been collected in as a String in this example.
    String appendedRowsFromFile = "NOTPROVIDED 3392076122/RFB/2006270519020060\n"
            + "dfgsaadsfdgfh 654323546723 gdfsgasgdfh 42354124354\n"
            + "3392076122 4031253506 RAMIN ABD ULJABAR AF/RFB/202006\n"
            + "dfgsaadsfdgfh 7e9587230957 gdfsgasgdfh 3049123845098\n"
            + "NOTPROVIDED 3392076122 EASTERN U/RFB/200627\n";

    String regex1 = "^\\w+\\s+(\\d+)/\\w+"; // "NOTPROVIDED 3392076122/RFB/2006270519020060\n"
    String regex2 = "^(\\d+)\\s+\\d+\\s+\\w+"; // "3392076122 4031253506 RAMIN ABD ULJABAR AF/RFB/202006\n"
    String regex3 = "^\\w+\\s+(\\d{10})\\s+\\w+"; // "NOTPROVIDED 3392076122 EASTERN U/RFB/200627\n"

    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(String.format("(?:%s|%s|%s)", regex1, regex2, regex3), Pattern.MULTILINE)
            .matcher(appendedRowsFromFile);
    while(matcher.find()) {
        String completeMatchNoGroup = matcher.group(0);
        Matcher matcher1 = Pattern.compile(regex1).matcher(completeMatchNoGroup);
        Matcher matcher2 = Pattern.compile(regex2).matcher(completeMatchNoGroup);
        Matcher matcher3 = Pattern.compile(regex3).matcher(completeMatchNoGroup);

        String wantedString = "NO_MATCH";
        if(matcher1.find()) {
            wantedString = matcher.group(1);
        } else if (matcher2.find()) {
            wantedString = matcher.group(2);
        } else if (matcher3.find()) {
            wantedString = matcher.group(3);
        }

        System.out.println("Extraction: \"" + wantedString + "\"");
        System.out.println("From match: " + completeMatchNoGroup);
        System.out.println("# # #");
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Extraction: "3392076122"
From match: NOTPROVIDED 3392076122/RFB
# # #
Extraction: "3392076122"
From match: 3392076122 4031253506 RAMIN
# # #
Extraction: "3392076122"
From match: NOTPROVIDED 3392076122 EASTERN
# # #
```